# PowerShell - How do I define multiple commands in alias?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

For example, if I type a command like this:

```
Get-Childitem | where-object {$_lastwritetime.Day -eq "$data"} |sort-object lastwrittetime
```

and I want to make an alias for it, I was trying do stuff like this:

```
set-alias Check -value (and there is above command)
```

then the alias works, but ignores commands after `Get-Childitem`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For example:

```
Get-CsAdUser –LdapFilter "Department=IT" | Format-Table DisplayName, Enabled, SipAddress –AutoSize
```

> So how do you create an alias for a command like that? Well, **you
>   don't**: PowerShell will only let you create aliases for cmdlets,
>   functions, scripts, or files.

So is there a way to work around this problem? Of course there is: there's always a way to work around a problem. (Well, except when there isn't.) For one thing, you could write a script that runs that command for you; there's definitely nothing wrong with that. However, an even better approach might be to create a function that runs your command for you. You know, a function that looks like this one:

```
Function itusers {Get-CsAdUser –LdapFilter "Department=IT" | Format-Table DisplayName, Enabled, SipAddress –AutoSize}
```

What we have here is a little function named itusers, a function that returns all the users in the IT department and then displays the value of the DisplayName, Enabled, and SipAddress attributes for each of those users (and in a nicely-formatted table to boot).

Instructions as seen in [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/csps/archive/2011/03/21/psaliasesandfunctions.aspx).