# Powershell - Set-alias doesn't accept paramters - python

Tags: python, powershell

Following this [tutorial](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/tutorial-powershell-aliases/) i want to set an alias for python autopep8.
the syntax described is.

```
Set-Alias gs Get-Service <enter>
```

So o copy that format i have done.

```
PS C:\Users\sayth> Set-Alias a8 autopep8 --in-place --aggressive --aggressive
```

However i receive an error

```
Set-Alias : A positional parameter cannot be found
that accepts argument '--in-place'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-Alias a8 autopep8 --in-place --aggressive
--aggressive
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:)
   [Set-Alias], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNo
   tFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetAliasCo
  mmand
```

What is the correct way to set an alias with paramters?

Comment: Have you tried using just one `-` before the parameters?

Comment: Also, the very first comment on that site mentions that aliases are for single words, not entire commands.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PowerShell - How do I define multiple commands in alias?](http://superuser.com/questions/527000/powershell-how-do-i-define-multiple-commands-in-alias)